# fetching specific columns using listFeed in googlesheet using java api

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to fetch only specific columns based on header in spreadsheet. 
I tried the following code

```
ListQuery query=new ListQuery(url);
query.setFields("FieldName");
```

but it gives the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Bad Request
Fields query parameter is not supported

at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:602)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1077)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:676)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.query(Service.java:1237)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.query(Service.java:1178)
```

Is there a way we can fetch only specific columns instead of listfeed by using ListQuery or url or is there another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select columns if you use the [Visualization Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

Example that selects columns B and C (2nd and 3rd) of a big sheet (from [this tutorial](http://acrl.ala.org/techconnect/?p=4001)):
https://docs.google.com/a/temet.ch/spreadsheets/d/1jwKyiVro8ZqPr5jRsyCN7igPJ76vOvtRy_xq3I8nKVI/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&gid=0&tq=select%20B,C

The query returns JSONP if you leave away the `tqx=out:html` parameter, but you won't get ListEntries.

Note that the column names are the native A, B, C... of the sheet, it doesn't use the headers in row 1 as the `ListFeed` does.

Comment: i tried doing that but i am getting the following exception :Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Bad Request Invalid request URI at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataReque‌​st.java:602) at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataR‌​equest.java:564) at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.jav‌​a:560) at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)

Comment: I think this is just a normal URL, no need for gdata. I don't think gdata allows such a URL.

Answer (score 0):

### ListFeed Example

http://gdata-java-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/sample/spreadsheet/list/ListDemo.java

But I feel "CellFeed" is better in almost every way.

There are a few other options if all you want to do is "read" data.

Comment: i tried cell feed but i found listfeed to be better as operations such as row delete etc can be done properly.. i looked into the listfeed link you gave me but there doesnt seem to be a way only selecting specific columns